# XSD Complex Decimal Type optional value

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

This is my XSD...

```
<element name="amount">
  <complexType>
    <simpleContent>
      <extension base="decimal">
        <attribute type="string" name="domain"/>
      </extension>
    </simpleContent>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

Will only pass if `<amount>` has a value. 
Whereas if I change it from decimal to string, `<amount>` doesn't have to have a value.  How to update the XSD to make it both decimal and being optional?